# Python implementation of AES and SHA256/512 that are FIPS-140-2 validated?

Tags: encryption, aes, sha, python, fips

For security purposes I  need to use AES encryption and SHA256/512 in my Django/Python project. I know there are various libraries out there that provide different encryption methods but I can't seem to find a library/package that is FIPS-140 validated. I was wondering if there is solution available for my need? if not which modules/packages are FIPS-140 compliance?

**EDIT**:

It seems that there is no FIPS-140-2 validated python package. However, AES, SHA-256 and SHA-512 are FIPS-140 compliance, so pycrypto or Cryptography can be used for AES encryption and SHA-256/512.

The closest I could get to a FIPS-140-2 conformance, is to build [OpenSSL FIPS Object Module](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140val-all.htm#1747) and [use it as the backend for Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#using-your-own-openssl-on-linux). But then again since we are using a wrapper, it probably needs to go through FIPS-140-2 validation process again.

Thanks to @TerryChia for his helpful comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the  [FIPS publication](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/PubsFIPS.html) you can see different annexes, in the [Annex A: Approved Security Functions](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips140-2/fips1402annexa.pdf) it says that `AES`, `SHA-256` and `SHA-512` are FIPS-140 compliance.

In the [FIPS-140 validated list](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140val-all.htm) however I can't see any python module. Therefore seems that there isn't a python module FIPS-140 compliance, so you can use whatever python cryptographic module want if it has an implementation for the algorithms that you mentioned, maybe you can use [pycrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto/2.6.1) to encrypt using `AES` or to generate a message digest. Also as you comment [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) could be a good possibility.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Do you know if [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) can be used with OpenSSL FIPS Object Module as its backend which is FIPS-140 validated?

Comment: [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) looks good, however I don't know If it can works with OpenSSL.

Comment: @nima Yes, there shouldn't be any problems with that. If there is, open up an issue on GitHub. (Source: I'm one of the developers.)

Comment: Thanks @TerryChia I'll give it a try then. How can I point [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) to the OpenSSL I build with FIPS Object Module?

Comment: @nima https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#using-your-own-openssl-on-linux

Comment: Thank you @TerryChia. But I assume just using OpenSSL FIPS Object Module as the backend doesn't make the whole thing FIPS 140-2 conformance, since we are using a wrapper, it needs to get validated again.

Comment: @nima I have *no idea* on that. I'm lucky enough to never have to concern myself about FIPS.

Comment: That certainly seems odd.  If you called it through the subprocess module, would that need to be validated again as well?  If the library itself has been validated, one would think that any "wrappers" that aren't altering the execution of the cryptographic primitives would be fine.  Otherwise, how would anyone do FIPS-compliant crypto?